# Multi Column RDLC report, with the data flowing from Right to Left

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Multi Column RDLC report, with the data flowing from Right to Left instead of Left to Right, Is that is possible
The easiest way please
*I am using Visual Studio 2010*

Answer (score 1):

you should use the 'TextAlign' property instead.

Select all the columns you want their text to be right-aligned, and on the property window (F4) you will find the 'TextAlign' property, Set it to 'Right'

Answer (score 0):

In BIDS, highlight all relevant fields and set the Direction property in the Properties window to be RTL.

Comment: All Direction and LayoutDirection are set to RTL